# Count or the Number of Columns That Meet Some Criteria

Tags: r, count, criteria

I'd like to create a new column that counts the number of conditions met across specific columns.

For example, using `mtcars`, the conditions might be as follows: 
`"disp" > 150, "hp < 100", "wt" > 2.65`

Looking at the top three rows - Mazda RX4, Mazda RX4 Wag, Datsun 710 - the new column, `mtcars$metcri`, should be 1, 2, and 1, respectively.

I've looked at a number of other articles and most focus on subsetting, [counting the total number of rows that match the criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195996/count-number-of-rows-matching-a-criteria/28196342), or using [one criteria across all the columns of concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358201/counting-the-number-of-columns-that-meet-a-logical-criteria). I did see something re using [if_else statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217703/how-to-sum-ifelse-statements-on-the-fly-with-r), but that didn't work and yielded 52 for the new column. Just in case I missed something, here is the code for that:

```
mtcars$metcri <- sum(if_else(mtcars$disp > 150, 1, 0, missing = NULL), 
                      if_else(mtcars$hp < 100, 1, 0, missing = NULL), 
                      if_else(mtcars$wt > 2.65, 1, 0, missing = NULL))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the three logical conditions directly

```
mtcars$metcri <- (mtcars$disp > 150)  +  (mtcars$hp < 100) + (mtcars$wt > 2.5)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for mtcars but in my dataset some of the rows are missing data for the columns I have criteria for and, as a result, the new column is just showing NA's. Thoughts on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `with`

```
mtcars$metcri <- with(mtcars, disp > 150 + hp < 100 + wt > 2.5)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, metcri := (disp > 150) + (hp < 100) + (wt > 2.5)]
```